# CreateProcessW() with EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT flag returns error code 87?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I'm struggling to get CreateProcessW under msvc to work with the EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT option. I've created a minimal example that calls ping.exe and redirects the stdout to a handle. This works fine without the EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT option (but is not thread safe), so trying to pass handles explicitly to child process as in minimal example below.

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <processthreadsapi.h>
#include <WinBase.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


void TestFunctionW()
{
    STARTUPINFOEXW startup_info = { 0 };
    PROCESS_INFORMATION process_info = { 0 };

    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr;

    // Set the bInheritHandle flag so pipe handles are inherited. 
    saAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

    HANDLE          m_hChildStd_OUT_Rd;
    HANDLE          m_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;

    // Create a pipe for the child process's STDOUT. (m_hChildStd_OUT_Wr->m_hChildStd_OUT_Rd)
    if (!CreatePipe(&m_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, &m_hChildStd_OUT_Wr, &saAttr, 0)) {
        std::cerr << "CreatePipe Failed" << endl;
    }

    // Ensure the read handle to the pipe for STDOUT is not inherited.
    if (!SetHandleInformation(m_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0)){
        std::cerr << "SetHandleInformation Failed" << endl;
    }


    startup_info.StartupInfo.hStdError = NULL;
    startup_info.StartupInfo.hStdOutput = m_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
    startup_info.StartupInfo.hStdInput = NULL;
    startup_info.StartupInfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;


    // Newstuff relating to handle lists
    BOOL fSuccess = true;
    BOOL fInitialized = FALSE;
    SIZE_T size = 0;
    LPPROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_LIST lpAttributeList = NULL;

    int cHandlesToInherit = 2;
    HANDLE rgHandlesToInherit[] = { m_hChildStd_OUT_Wr, m_hChildStd_OUT_Rd };

    if (fSuccess) {
        fSuccess = InitializeProcThreadAttributeList(NULL, 1, 0, &size) || GetLastError() == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER;
    }
    if (fSuccess) {
        lpAttributeList = reinterpret_cast<LPPROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_LIST>(HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, size));
        fSuccess = lpAttributeList != NULL;
    }
    if (fSuccess) {
        fSuccess = InitializeProcThreadAttributeList(lpAttributeList, 1, 0, &size);
    }
    if (fSuccess) {
        fInitialized = TRUE;
        fSuccess = UpdateProcThreadAttribute(lpAttributeList,
            0, PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_HANDLE_LIST,
            rgHandlesToInherit,
            cHandlesToInherit * sizeof(HANDLE), NULL, NULL);
    }

    if (!fSuccess) {
        cerr << "Handle list stuff failed" << endl;
        exit(-1);
    }

    startup_info.lpAttributeList = lpAttributeList;

    cerr << "Handle stuff succeeded.." << endl;


    startup_info.StartupInfo.cb = sizeof(startup_info);

    DWORD flags = EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT;
    //DWORD flags = 0;

    std::wstring cmd(L"ping.exe");
    BOOL ret = CreateProcessW(NULL, (LPWSTR)cmd.c_str(), NULL, NULL, FALSE, flags, NULL, NULL, (LPSTARTUPINFOW)&startup_info, &process_info);
    if (!ret)
    {
        DWORD err = GetLastError();
        std::cout << "Failed: code " << err << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv)
{
    TestFunctionW();
}
```

Error code 87 appears to mean invalid parameters.

I compiled the example under MSVC 2017. Without the option DWORD flags = EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT; it works fine (as expected), with the option it fails with error code 87 (not expected).

Comment: Unrelated, but you don't need to `#include` any of the other Windows headers, `<windows.h>` should be enough.

Comment: `(LPWSTR)cmd.c_str()` -- This is undefined behavior, since `CreateProcessW` can modify the string contents.  Don't do the cast and provide the correct type to the function without casting.  In general, if you find yourself applying C-style casts to string and/or character pointer types, that is a sign you are doing something wrong.  Unless you know *exactly* what you're doing, either call the correct functions that takes the string type without casting, or provide the correct types without casting.

Comment: Regarding the command from @PaulMcKenzie, please read [the `CreateProcessW` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw), about its `lpCommandLine` argument.

Comment: @OP And at the link: *The Unicode version of this function, CreateProcessW, can modify the contents of this string. Therefore, this parameter cannot be a pointer to read-only memory (such as a const variable or a literal string). If this parameter is a constant string, the function may cause an access violation.* -- Since `c_str()` returns a `const` character pointer, you basically coded yourself right into what the documentation says you shouldn't be doing.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'm pretty sure a `const_cast` only results in undefined behavior when writing through the non-const pointer to a const object. Here, however, `cmd` is non-const. Assuming C++17, using `cmd.data()` instead would be preferable still.

Comment: Do `cmd.data()` or `&cmd[0]` guarantee the presence of the NUL terminator?  And `cmd.c_str()` has a contract that you won't change the contents (this leads to undefined behavior even if the `const_cast` didn't).

Comment: @BenVoigt Starting with C++11, `c_str()` and `data()` are required to "perform the same function", so, yes, `data()` necessarily must return a zero-terminated string. Though I was wrong; modifying the underlying character array through `c_str()` or the const `data()` pointers is explicitly called out as UB.

Comment: If it's C++17 or greater, using `cmd.data()` should be ok, or C++11 or greater, `&cmd[0]` should be ok, both not needing any casts.  If this is C++03 or C++98, then the code is just plain wrong, without question.

Comment: I just tested with VS 2022.  Without the cast, the code fails to compile using C++11.  Using `cmd.data()`, it also fails to compile under C++11.  Using `&cmd[0]`, the code compiles under C++11.  Using C++17, `data()` compiles without casting.  @OP -- This all may be nitpicking, but if you ever get crashes or strange behavior, I suggest you remove the `LPWSTR` cast and fix the code as described.

Answer (score 6):

According to the [`UpdateProcThreadAttribute` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-updateprocthreadattribute), you must enable handle inheritance when using `PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_HANDLE_LIST`:

> **Note**  if you use this attribute, pass in a value of `TRUE` for the `bInheritHandles` parameter of the `CreateProcess` function.

That's the 5th argument, where you're passing `FALSE`. Therefore, the handles aren't inherited, and in the child process the handles are invalid -> error 87.

---

Problem #2: You're passing more handles than necessary, including one that can't be inherited:

```
// Ensure the read handle to the pipe for STDOUT is not inherited.
SetHandleInformation(m_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0);
HANDLE rgHandlesToInherit[] = { m_hChildStd_OUT_Wr, m_hChildStd_OUT_Rd };
```

`m_hChildStd_OUT_Rd` is only needed by the parent, and you've marked it to forbid inheritance.  So don't place it into the `PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_HANDLE_LIST`.

Comment: You are correct (I had it right in the full example). Unfortunately it still giveserror code 87 even with this fixed.

Comment: @DerekMagee: That fix will make one of your handles legal in the child, unfortunately the other still fails to inherit resulting in an invalid value (the child has no business using it anyway)

Comment: That (just passing 1 handle) fixed it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @DerekMagee Another useful resource is [Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output).

Comment: @DerekMagee Could you update your code with the working change, so this is possible to copy paste? The hint that INVALID_PARAMETER occurs due to missing inheritance was also helpful.
Would be nice, if the Windows examples wouild be complete and with some hints like this.

Comment: @Jay-Pi: No, the code in the question must continue to demonstrate the problem, so that the question and answers make sense for future readers.  The value on this site is in the *explanations*; you should not be copy-pasting anyway.